# meteor pass data into modal from link

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm trying to pass an ID from a href into a modal that opens when the link is clicked.

I've got the modal popping Ok, but instead of the id in the link, I'm getting the ID of the parent page in this.

My code for the link is

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
   <tbody
           <tr>
               <th>Posted</th>
               <th>ID</th>
           </tr>
           {{#each quotes}}
               <tr>
                  <td>{{submittedText}}</td>
                  <td><a href="#showQuote" class="showQuote" data-toggle="modal">{{_id}}</a></td>
               </tr>
           {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

The correct quote id is in the table, but I can't work out how to get this quote id to appear in the resulting modal that opens.

I tried trapping the click event in a helper as follows

```
  'click #showQuote' : function(t,e) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(t);
    console.log(e);
    debugger;
  }
```

But this is the parent ID not the quote one (and this only seems to trigger when I close the dialogue anyway).

How do I pass this in please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already implemented the code to show the modal you could use a session variable

```
<template name="modalstuff">
    ...
   {{#with quoteinfo}}
      MODAL HERE   
      ...
   {{/with}}
</template>

Template.modalstuff.helpers({
    quoteinfo: function() {
        return Session.get("quotedata");
    }
});
```

Then in your template where you have the link

```
Template.template_with_modal_link.events({
    'click . showQuote': function() {
         Session.set('quotedata', this);
     }
});
```

`this` is the data context around the showQuote link, which would then be interfaced with the Session variable to the modal

Comment: If I change my ref by giving it an id="showQuote" and catch the event as you show (based on the ID) I get the ID of the quote in the handler, but, I don't get the modal to pop (I get the background) because the app is trying to show a url with #showQuote on the end which doesn't exist. If I remove the ID and catch the #showQuote, I get the underlying Page on exit of the modal, nothing on entry...??

Comment: @PeterNUnn sorry I had a typo in the code from copy pasting, its supposed to use the class `click .showQuote` (i had an extra space after the .). Fixed now.

Comment: Thank ok @Akshat I got that, but its still not popping the dialog. When I put the id in it gets added to the url for the link and the modal doesn't show up.

Comment: @PeterNUnn ok, maybe something's going wrong with binding, you can manually show it with `$('#showQuote').modal('show');` in the click handler. Be careful with `id=`, you can use it only once, if you're doing it to your `a` tag it would mean they all have the same `id`

Comment: Got it.. thanks, needed to add an extra class to the reference and turn them into buttons to get them to work properly (not sure why the buttons, but the links don't work).

Answer (score 4):

A session variable is one way to do it, but if you use the [peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal) package, you can pass the parent context into the show function.

javascript

```
Template.template_with_modal_link.events({
    'click . showQuote': function() {
         Modal.show('<ModalName>', this);    // parent context this
 } });
```

html

```
<template name="<ModalName>">
    <!-- modal format -->
</template>
```